# Is it 'sleep-induced coma' or 'coma-induced sleep'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I had originally written coma-induced and was told it was 'sleep-induced coma'.

Which one is correct?

> **sleep-induced coma**
>
> **coma-induced sleep**

Comment: I don't think that either one is valid.

Comment: We should all be terrified if sleep can induce comas. Imagine going to bed and waking up in a coma! (heh.)

Comment: I think that once or twice, while writing late at night, I have had trouble with sleep induced commas.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think either of those are common phrases. Usually, "medically-induced coma" is a common induced coma term.

I asked a **Board Certified Anesthesiologist**. His response:

> "Sleep-induced coma" and "coma-induced sleep" are phrases that don't
>   really make much sense. You can't really induce a coma from sleep, and
>   you wouldn't really induce sleep from a coma. It's just called being
>   in a coma. So, no, neither of those are common medical phrases.

Right from the horse's mouth! So if someone's coma is induced from medicine, then it's a "medically-induced coma". Otherwise, they "fell into a coma" or are just plain "in a coma".

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure "coma" and "sleep" are very different things medically speaking. "Sleep" is a normal brain function that has specific things happening in it (deep sleep, REM sleep...). "Coma" is a state of unconsciousness related to brain damage. In that sense "coma-induced sleep" would be wrong because if you are in a coma you are very unlikely to be sleeping. While "sleep-induced coma" could mean you are putting someone to sleep to induce a coma; that's probably where the phrase, which Google confirms exists, originates. But as you say "medically induced coma" is the correct form.

Comment: "Sleep induced coma" appears to be the name of a song.  Other than that, the Google references appear to be either a sort of slang term for being groggy from sleep deprivation, or a misstatement by non-professionals for what they were likely told was a "drug-induced coma".

Comment: @medica Once I spoke to my doctor friend, I removed the sentence that said they were similar. (Never said they're the same things, though.)

Comment: @ProgrammingEqualsSuperpower - They appear similar superficially, I agree. But as Rozenn stated, they are quite different.